# Going from Parallel.ForEach to Multithreading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

So I converted a recursive function to iterative and then used Parallel.ForEach but when I was running it through VTune it was only really using 2 logical cores at for the majority of its run time.

I decided to attempt to use managed threads instead, and converted this code:

```
for (int N = 2; N <= length; N <<= 1)
{
    int maxThreads = 4;
    var workGroup = Enumerable.Range(0, maxThreads);

    Parallel.ForEach(workGroup, i =>
    {
        for (int j = ((i / maxThreads) * length); j < (((i + 1) / maxThreads) * length); j += N)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < N / 2; k++)
            {
                int evenIndex = j + k;
                int oddIndex = j + k + (N / 2);

                var even = output[evenIndex];
                var odd = output[oddIndex];

                output[evenIndex] = even + odd * twiddles[k * (length / N)];
                output[oddIndex] = even + odd * twiddles[(k + (N / 2)) * (length / N)];
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Into this:

```
for (int N = 2; N <= length; N <<= 1)
{
    int maxThreads = 4;

    Thread one = new Thread(() => calculateChunk(0, maxThreads, length, N, output));
    Thread two = new Thread(() => calculateChunk(1, maxThreads, length, N, output));
    Thread three = new Thread(() => calculateChunk(2, maxThreads, length, N, output));
    Thread four = new Thread(() => calculateChunk(3, maxThreads, length, N, output));

    one.Start();
    two.Start();
    three.Start();
    four.Start();
}

public void calculateChunk(int i, int maxThreads, int length, int N, Complex[] output)
{
    for (int j = ((i / maxThreads) * length); j < (((i + 1) / maxThreads) * length); j += N)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < N / 2; k++)
        {
            int evenIndex = j + k;
            int oddIndex = j + k + (N / 2);
            var even = output[evenIndex];
            var odd = output[oddIndex];

            output[evenIndex] = even + odd * twiddles[k * (length / N)];
            output[oddIndex] = even + odd * twiddles[(k + (N / 2)) * (length / N)];
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is in the fourth thread on the last iteration of the `N` loop I get a index out of bounds exception for the output array where the index is attempting access the equivalent of the `length`.

I can not pinpoint the cause using debugging, but I believe it is to do with the threads, I ran the code without the threads and it worked as intended.

If any of the code needs changing let me know, I usually have a few people suggest edits. Thanks for your help, I have tried to sort it myself and am fairly certain the problem is occurring in my threading but I can not see how.

PS: The intended purpose is to parallelize this segment of code.

Comment: [Parallel.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx) has many overload, you can control the degree of parallelism with options.

Comment: You could potentially achieve the desired outcome simply by moving `Parallel.ForEach` from the inner loop to the outer loop of your original snippet (if you expect it'll have more elements than `workGroup` of course). That'll reduce `Parallel.ForEach` setup and teardown costs and allow the load balancer to better do its job and I expect it'll scale up to N cores. If you're sticking with threads though, I'm expecting to see `Join`s somewhere - otherwise you're starting more and more threads on each loop iteration before the previous batch has the chance to finish.

Comment: Are you sure your algorithm is correct? As of my understanding, in the loop `for (int j = ((i / maxThreads) * length); j < (((i + 1) / maxThreads) * length); j += N)` the inital value `int j = ((i / maxThreads) * length` will always be 0 for i in the range [0,maxThreads-1] (this is integer division!). And the loop condition ` j < (((i + 1) / maxThreads) * length)` will be `false` for all `i` values except the last one. So in the end, you're inner loop is entered only once, no matter how many threads you use.

Comment: Never mind `Thread`.  You just stepped over a trip-wire, right into a mine-field.  The TPL is a lot smarter than you give it credit for--you don't have to manually throttle the number of items you hand to `Parallel.ForEach` to the number of cores you have.  In fact, it will never reach that number because you're not allowing the thread pool to scale to your actual load.

Comment: @qbik You're exactly right and I figured that out shortly after posting, I have since corrected the issue but another has arise whereby splitting the workload is what is causing the index out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observed behaviour is almost certainly due to the use of a captured loop iteration variable `N`. I can reproduce your situation with a simple test:

```
ConcurrentBag<int> numbers = new ConcurrentBag<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => numbers.Add(i));

    t.Start();
    //t.Join(); // Uncomment this to get expected behaviour.
}

// You'd not expect this assert to be true, but most of the time it will be.
Assert.True(numbers.Contains(10000));
```

Put simply, your `for` loop is racing to increment `N` before the value of `N` can be copied by the delegate that executes the `calculateChunk` call. As a result `calculateChunk` sees almost random values of `N` going up to (and including) `length <<= 1` - that's what's causing your `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

The output values you'll get will be rubbish too as you can never rely on the value of `N` being correct.

If you want to *safely* rewrite the original code to utilize more cores, move `Parallel.ForEach` from the inner loop to the outer loop. If the number of outer loop iterations is high, the load balancer will be able to do its job properly (which it can't with your current `workGroup` count of 4 - that number of elements is simply too low).

Comment: Just pig-piling to emphasize **safe**.  This code should rest easily on the TPL (`Parallel.ForEach`).  Running off to raw `Thread`s is dangerous NIH.

Comment: Each increment of N uses the calculated data from the previous iteration so I can't Parallelize it, its a data dependency :(

Comment: @OliverGiess, I understand now. I also think you've marked my answer way too soon. It's an interesting parallelization problem due to the need to scan previous results. I can see how this can be solved with a producer-consumer approach and barriers, but I am not confident that the performance boost from parallelization will outweigh the synchronization overheads.

Comment: Yeah I dont mind I think I am going to take the approach of using a thread pool, and just queuing a range of the k loops to each thread as it opens. I have opened another question one which more specifically outlines the issue I discovered, initially I thought it was to do with my use of threads, I later realized it was to do with the inverse nature of the enclosed loops. But my other question more acutely covers the topic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539345/inner-and-outerloop-inverse-workloads-need-to-distribte-evenly